# expand an images padding over other elements using only CSS

Tags: html, css, image

I have a gallery of images. When you hover over an image the padding expands and it gets a shadow effect.

Is it possible to have the padding expand over the other images? So the change in the padding does not distort any other thing on the page?

Here is the code I have -- http://jsfiddle.net/U6VNx/ --

**CSS**

```
div.gallery {margin:0 auto; width:900px;}

div.images {text-align:center; width:900px;}

div.images a {width:259px; height:254px; }

div.images a img {padding:5px; transition:padding .5s, box-shadow .5s;}

div.images a img:hover {padding:20px; box-shadow:0 0 8px #000000; overflow:hidden;}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your simple example, you could just use a `margin:-15px` for the hovered images, and have that transitioned as well:

```
div.images a img {padding:5px; transition:margin .5s, padding .5s, box-shadow .5s;}
div.images a img:hover {margin:-15px; padding:20px;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/U6VNx/2/

Comment: would there be a way to make the expanded padding not transparent?

Comment: A `background-color` for the image would be shown in its padding area …

Comment: Just add this : div.images a img:hover {margin:-15px; padding:20px; box-shadow:0 0 8px #000000; overflow:hidden; background-color:orange}

Comment: Thanks for that, I did not think a background-color would also color the padding